# what kind of fields in network packets should be converted to network byte order

Tags: networking, tcp, network-programming

I know the endianess on hosts and network may be different
but why the byte order is important?

I think there are two reasons:

1 for the router to check the ip header(likeaddresses), the routers only recognize big-endian order(network byte order)
2 for the receiving host to recognize the byte order of the packets. Since the receiving host doesn't know the byte order of the sending host, if the byte order is not converted to network byte order, it doesn't know the packet byte order.

am I right?

so for the following fields, which should be converted to byte order, and why?

```
1 TCP/UDP Header options, like MSS, timestamps
2 TCP/UDP header checksum
3 TCP sequence number
4 UDP/TCP data fields
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every field that is sent/stored as binary data (not ASCII, in particular) that is longer than a single byte needs to have a well-defined byte order. Otherwise, as you indicated, the receiver doesn't know how to interpret what the sender sent.

The answer to your specific question is that #1, #2, and #3 need to be in network byte order. As for the fields in the UDP/TCP payload (#4), that's up to you. Network byte order (big endian) is suggested, for consistency with almost every other protocol, but if you are defining a protocol then you can choose little endian if you want. Some have.

Comment: but I wrote a program where the checksum(2 bytes) is not converted to network byte order, they can be accepted correctly.....

Comment: for the data field, if the sending machine has different byte order with the receiving machine, what will happend? and how to deal with the inconsistency problem?

Comment: If the sending and receiving machine don't have the same byte order and the protocol does not mandate a canonical byte order, then the receiver will interpret what the sender sent as garbage. And how to deal with the inconsistency is to choose and mandate a specific byte order in the protocol, or else transmit everything as textual data rather than binary.

Comment: textual data is still with byte order problem, isn't it? besides, if the byte order is a problem, then how the website deliver their web pages? for example, if the web server is big-endian while the client is little-endian?

Comment: textual data in almost any encoding (ASCII, UTF-8, etc...) does not have a byte order problem because either the code units are single bytes or the order is well defined. Websites are able to deliver web pages without worrying about byte order because the entire HTTP protocol (requests, responses, and headers) is text-based. HTML is also text-based so that's not a problem. Images are binary though, and when websites deliver those, it could have been a problem, except that image formats such as PNG always mandate a particular byte order for their multibyte fields to avoid exactly this problem.