# Network Byte Order for sin_family

Tags: python, c, networking, endianness

I'm sending a UDP message from python on an Ubuntu box to a C program on a vxworks machine.  The Endianness on the vxworks machine does not match Network Byte Order, so I'm forced to swap byte order around using ntohs, ntohl, etc.

I'm reading from the UDP connection and then attempting to determine the "family" so I know if I should decode things are IPV4 or IPV6.  I'd like to do something like this... but it doesn't work.

```
struct sockaddr data = {};
char udp_ip[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN] = {0};
// ... (recvfrom ...)
if (AF_INET == data.sa_family)
{
    struct sockaddr_in*s = (struct sockaddr_in *)&data;
    const char *addr = inet_ntop(AF_INET, &s->sin_addr, udp_ip, sizeof(udp_ip));
    udp_port = ntohs(s->sin_port);
    ...
}
if (AF_INET6 == data.sa_family)
{
    struct sockaddr_in6 *s = (struct sockaddr_in *)&data;
    const char *addr = inet_ntop(AF_INET6, &s->sin6_addr, udp_ip, sizeof(udp_ip));
    udp_port = ntohs(s->sin6_port);
    ...
}
```

I'm used to seeing the port, and similar fields swapped, but I found that the family is a multi-byte field.  I found that code doesn't work because my sa_family value is way out of range.  In my headers for this machine, the largest AF_* value is 40.  I'm seeing a value over 500.   I looks like the bytes on sa_family are swapped and I need to swap their byte order as well.   Something like :

```
const sa_family_t family = ntohs(data.sa_family);
```

Then I would use that family variable in the if checks.   **QUESTION** : Is this reasonable?  I've never seen ntoh* done on the family before.   I'm surprised it is multi byte (sizeof(data.sa_family) == 2).

I don't think my python code is relevant, but for completeness..

```
udp_sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
udp_sock.bind(('', 0))
data = self.create_data()
udp_sock.sendto(data, (ip, port))
```

The data sent is sort of irrelevant as I'm stuck before I even get to parse the data and the problem presents itself if the data is as simple as "FOO".

Other Articles I've checked : [what kind of fields in network packets should be converted to network byte order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15526598/what-kind-of-fields-in-network-packets-should-be-converted-to-network-byte-order) as well as  [Network byte order and endianness issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22889283/network-byte-order-and-endianness-issues).

I also read over this, which seems to contradict what I am seeing.  [struct sockaddr_in member byte order for bind()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44274977/struct-sockaddr-in-member-byte-order-for-bind)

Likewise, conversely, (but not shown), when sending a message back from my vxworks (non-network byte order machine) back to my other machine I have to htons(AF_INET) when setting up the message or it doesn't work.   I'm just confused as I'm seeing contradictory advice here on SO so I assume I must be doing something else fundamentally wrong.  **QUESTION** : If the advice that you do NOT need to convert the family (htons/ntohs), what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Unrelated to your question, you should swap the two operands here `if (AF_INET6 == data.sa_family)`. It works yes but the other way is the normal way, i.e. `variable == constant`

Comment: where do you populate the `data` variable? are you making sure your python code is converting everything to network byte order before sending?

Comment: As you say family field should not need conversion. It is not sent over the network but used by the drivers to know how to build the packets.

Comment: That is what I thought.  It looked like the value there was being populated at a low level from the IP protocol field (1 byte) value of 17 (UDP).

Comment: only the actual network structures (the stuff that is actually sent on wire) are in network byte order - an unfortunate abstraction leak through the socket APIs :/

Comment: The address family includes things like `AF_UNIX` that  not part of the IP protocol suite at all...

Comment: Actually if you carefully read the other question, it explains why and how `sa_family` need not be swapped...

Comment: I missed it apparently.   How is IPV4 vs IPV6 determined?   Is that in the parsing of the IP packet... the version field?  IP, version = 4 vs IP, version = 6.  Duh.

Comment: Anyone want to throw that into an answer so I can close this?

Comment: why are using sockaddr_in in ipv6 processing? should be sockaddr_in6

Comment: @HansPetterTaugbølKragset - I have a peer who is adamant it should be `if (constant == variable)` because if you accidentally write `constant = variable` (accidental assignment) it will cause a compiler error, while `variable = constant` will not (although it might trigger a warning).  I understand their reasoning, but still find `variable == constant` much easier to read.

Comment: @AndrewCottrell Our coding standard indicates const == variable, so that's what I do.  Depending on your compiler and its settings it may notify you, but not all do.

Answer (score 1):

Family does NOT need to be converted.  It isn't transmitted per se.   See :

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6

If the version value is 4, its IP version==4... IPV4.   If its version ==6.. then IPV6.

The real problem was that I was cross-compiling and I had the wrong version of the target's header files.   I had one where the structure was like this :

```
struct sockaddr {
    u_short sa_family;              /* address family */
    char    sa_data[14];            /* up to 14 bytes of direct address */
};
```

When, on the real system, the structure included another field :

```
/*
 * Structure used by kernel to store most
 * addresses.
 */
struct sockaddr {
    unsigned char   sa_len;      /* total length */
    sa_family_t     sa_family;   /* address family */
    char            sa_data[14]; /* actually longer; address value */
};
#define SOCK_MAXADDRLEN 255     /* longest possible addresses */
```

That extra character and the endian was the source of my problems.   I was seeing a value like 528.  That being the combination of the "10" in length and "2" in family when the bytes were combined and treated as a two byte unsigned.

Comment: Had exactly the same problem. Thank you so much!